# Finding the root of an equation (divergence at some points)

Tags: python, optimization

[enter image description here][1]

I am trying to solve this equation for a range of VSL [0.001,1] to obtain the values of delta_l. I have tried Fsolve with python which gives results where the values of VSL are between [0.001,0.1] when I put an initial guess of delta l that is close to the solution. But, when I vary the initial guess I don't obtain any solution for the whole range. I tried also scipy root with all the methods provided and I did not obtain any solution. When I tried with EA such as Genetic Algorithm it seems to give results but with the limitation of the range of solution provided, for instance, if I choose the range of solution for detla_l to be from [0.001,0.065] I get the solution I am actually looking for but if I widen the range or narrow it I obtain a different solution. Ideally, I would give a range of solutions that may fall in let's say [0.0001,0.2] and the algorithm would give the same results as when I give a range of [0.001,0.065].

From this I understand that the algorithm is not converging toward the solution of the equation (zero 0) and I need a better tool to make it converge.

Please if you have any thoughts I would be grateful.

#Editted

As a matter of fact, the final solution I would be looking to obtain is VSG. I will first obtain the delta_l value from solving the mentioned equation then calculate VSG from the following equation.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The following graph is a reference which I need to reproduce the same graph with my code.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

and here is the graph that I generated.
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

The code I wrote is below. and the main problem is the range of solutions for (delta_l) that I need to specify to get the desired results, for my case here I put [0.001,0.065] but I should not narrow it as I will not know the solution in another case (different Data) rather I would put an acceptable range let's say [0.0001,0.2] and would still expect to get similar results which is not the case.

```py
import pygad
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

D= 0.06  ### Diameter (m)
ROL= 997.9 #### Density liquid  Kg/m3
ROG= 1.2  ##### density gas    kg/m3
UL= 1.1*(10**(-3))### viscosit Pa.S
UG= 0.000018  ### viscosit Pa.S
G= 9.81   # gravitational acceleration  m/s2
sigma= 0.06    #### Interfacial tension  N/m
SL=3.14*D
### constants


list_of_derivatives=[]
list_of_interfacial_tension=[]
list_of_interfacial_tension_gas=[]
    
list_of_VSG=[]   ###### main values we are looking for



alpha= 20   #### inclination from horizontal   Degrees
list_of_liquid_velocities_VSL= np.linspace(0.001,1,80) #va


##################### barneaaaaaa   ##############

for VSL in list_of_liquid_velocities_VSL: 
    AL=3.14*(D**2)*(0.01-0.01**2)
    
    DL=4*AL/SL
    A=3.14*(0.5*D)**2
    VL=VSL*A/AL
    if (D*ROL*VSL/(UL))<2300:
        n=1
        CL=16
        m=0.2
        CG=0.046
        
       
    else:
        n=0.2
        CL=0.046
        m=0.2
        CG=0.046
        
        
    desired_output = 0
    
    def fitness_func(x,x_idx):
        derivative = ((G*(ROL-ROG)*D*math.sin(alpha*3.14/180)*((1-2*x)**2-2*(x-x**2)))-((CL/16)*ROL*((D*ROL/UL)**(-n))*(VSL**(2-n))*(((x-x**2)+(1-2*x)**2)/(x-x**2)**3)))

        fitness = (1/np.abs(derivative - desired_output))
        
        return fitness

    fitness_function = fitness_func

    num_generations = 100
    num_parents_mating = 4

    sol_per_pop = 8
    num_genes = 1
    init_range_low = 0.001
    init_range_high = 0.101

    parent_selection_type = "sss"
    keep_parents = 1

    crossover_type = "single_point"

    mutation_type = "random"
    mutation_percent_genes = 20

    gene_space = [{'low': 0.001, 'high': 0.065}]
    ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=num_generations,
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating,
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,
                       sol_per_pop=sol_per_pop,
                       num_genes=num_genes,
                       init_range_low=init_range_low,
                       init_range_high=init_range_high,
                       parent_selection_type=parent_selection_type,
                       keep_parents=keep_parents,
                       crossover_type=crossover_type,
                       mutation_type=mutation_type,
                       mutation_percent_genes=mutation_percent_genes,
                       gene_space= gene_space)


    ga_instance.run()

    x, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
    
   

    derivative = ((G*(ROL-ROG)*D*np.sin(alpha*3.14/180)*((1-2*x)**2-2*(x-x**2)))-((CL/16)*ROL*((D*ROL/UL)**(-n))*(VSL**(2-n))*(((x-x**2)+(1-2*x)**2)/(x-x**2)**3))) ### should be equal to 0


    list_of_derivatives.append(abs(derivative))
    
    interfacial_tenstion=((G*(ROL-ROG)*D*np.sin(alpha*3.14/180)*(x-x**2)*(1-2*x))+((CL/32)*ROL*(D*ROL/UL)**(-n)*VSL**(2-n)*((1-2*x)/(x-x**2)**2)))  ### should be equal to interfacial_tension_gas
    VSG  =  (interfacial_tenstion*((1-2*x)**4) /((0.5)*(CG)*((D*ROG/UG)**(-m))*(1+300*x)*(ROG)))**(1/(2-m))
    
    list_of_interfacial_tension.append(interfacial_tenstion)
    
    interfacial_tension_gas= ((((VSG)**(2-m))*(0.5)*(CG)*((D*ROG/UG)**(-m))*(1+300*x)*(ROG))/((1-2*x)**4))/(G*(ROL-ROG)*D)  ### this should equal to interfacial_tension
    list_of_interfacial_tension_gas.append(interfacial_tension_gas)
    
    list_of_VSG.append(VSG)
    
    
VSLexperiment= [0.02,0.06,0.1]
VSGexperiment=[13.94,14.54,19.09]

plt.plot()
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xlim(1,100)
plt.ylim(0.001,1)
plt.xlabel("VSG", fontsize=9)
plt.ylabel("VSL",fontsize=9)
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls=":", color='0.002', linewidth=0.4)
plt.scatter(VSGexperiment,VSLexperiment, color="Black", linewidth="0.05", label="VsgExperiment")
plt.plot (list_of_VSG,list_of_liquid_velocities_VSL, label='VBarnea', color='blue')    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0gLr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBXzY.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRd8I.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wiOg.png
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: @PaulCornelius I tried multiple algorithms but still, I didn't get the expected results. when I solve the equation (def fitness_func) with values of VSL from (0.1,1) The algorithm change the results with changing the range of solutions gene_space = [{'low': 0.001, 'high': 0.065}]. Here is the main challenge

Comment: Are your results just unexpected, or are they wrong?  A wrong result, for a root-finding algorithm, is such that when you plug it back into the formula, it doesn't give you zero.  An unexpected result is one where your formula, your code, or perhaps your understanding is at fault.  As the wikipedia link demonstrates, root-finding often presents some tricky math problems.